# lambda capture member variable by this

Tags: c++, lambda

To capture a member data in object, the lambda need capture 'this' pointer:

```
class A {
public:
    void func() {
       auto f = [this](){_b->do_something();};
       _c->run(f); // asynchronized method
    }
private:
    B* _b;
    C* _c;
};
```

There is a problem: when f gets called by _c, object of A may be destory! Will `_b->do_something();` become an undefined behavior?

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: You are *not* capturing any member data with this. You are capturing the value of `this` only.

Comment: How are you going to call `A::func()` if A is destroyed?

Comment: Yup. Check if `_b` is valid before you do `_b->do_something()`

Comment: In a word... yes. That will be UB.

Comment: @RaviShenoy You can't check if `_b` is valid because the `A` instance it was in is already dead.

Comment: @JamesRoot I guess OP is talking about the instance `B` being destroyed. If `A` is destroyed, there is no way you can call function `func()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From 3.8 Object life

> 5. [...] after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which
>      the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that refers to
>      the storage location where the object will be or was located may be
>      used but only in limited ways. [...] The program has undefined
>      behavior if:
>
> [...]
>
> 5.2 the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a
>   non-static member function of the object

So yes, using pointer to B in destroyed A is UB.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of a `shared_ptr`, and then capture that in the lambda. Now when you create the instance of `A` you will need to do so with `make_shared`. It's best if you inherit from `enable_shared_from_this` and then you can use `shared_from_this` in the lambda capture to force the `A` to stay around for long enough for the lambda to run without needing to have a reference to the `shared_ptr` anywhere else.

The first part of your class will look something like this:

```
class A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
    void func() {
       auto self = shared_from_this();
       auto f = [this, self](){_b.do_something();};
       _c->run(f); // asynchronized method
    }
```